# помогите разобраться как декомпилировать предположительно машинный код

Tags: ассемблер

Может быть есть прога которая поможет декомпилировать вот такой код, и что это за разновидность машинного кода. Это было в файле .exe:

```
4d5a 5000 0200 0000 0400 0f00 ffff 0000
b800 0000 0000 0000 4000 1a00 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000
ba10 000e 1fb4 09cd 21b8 014c cd21 9090
5468 6973 2070 726f 6772 616d 206d 7573
7420 6265 2072 756e 2075 6e64 6572 2057
696e 3332 0d0a 2437 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
5045 0000 4c01 0800 195e 422a 0000 0000
```

Comment: нулей слишком много. среди кода их быть не может в таком количестве.

Comment: Загружаешь в любом дизассемблере, и выгружаешь дамп. Тот-же Olly тебе в помощь https://www.ollydbg.de/odbg64.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Может быть есть прога которая поможет декомпилировать вот такой код

Эта прога называется HEX-редактор. Загружаешь в него дамп, и получаешь (в данном случае) РЕ-заголовок исполняемого файла *.exe:

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  4D 5A 50 00 02 00 00 00 04 00 0F 00 FF FF 00 00  MZP.........яя..
00000010  B8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 1A 00 00 00 00 00  ё.......@.......
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00  ................
00000040  BA 10 00 0E 1F B4 09 CD 21 B8 01 4C CD 21 90 90  є....ґ.Н!ё.LН!ђђ
00000050  54 68 69 73 20 70 72 6F 67 72 61 6D 20 6D 75 73  This program mus
00000060  74 20 62 65 20 72 75 6E 20 75 6E 64 65 72 20 57  t be run under W
00000070  69 6E 33 32 0D 0A 24 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  in32..$7........
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000A0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000B0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000C0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000D0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000E0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000F0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000100  50 45 00 00 4C 01 08 00 19 5E 42 2A 00 00 00 00  PE..L....^B*....
```